# How to set threading mode in SQLite with Entity Framework?

Tags: multithreading, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I'm using SQLite with Entity Framework Core (RC1).

I read, that [SQLite supports three different threading modes: Single-thread, Multi-thread and Serialized](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html).

How do I set in run-time, which mode I want to use with my database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` references the `SQLitePCRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3` NuGet package. That package contains a version of SQLite that has been compiled with `SQLITE_THREADSAFE=1` (Serialized). `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` doesn't currently expose an API to change this, nor did `System.Data.SQLite`.

See also [aspnet/EntityFramework#5466](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5466).

Comment: Is there any chance that in future it will be possible to set threadsafe option?

Comment: So If I understand this correctly, it should be safe to access this db in multiple threads? The underlying db connection will handle the locking and ensure serial / sequential access?

Comment: @Zapnologica Correct. Just be sure to use one SqliteConnection object per thread

Answer (score 1):

It is accomplished by opening a database with the appropriate flags set.  `SQLITE_OPEN_NOMUTEX` for multithread or `SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX` for serialized.  It looks like flag setting is available through the C interface:

https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_open_autoproxy.html

So if you aren't using the C interface directly, you are at the mercy of EF and whether they have decided to support flag setting on database open.